# tackle different types of utf hyphens in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode, text-normalization

We have different types of hyphens/dashes (in some text) populated in db. Before comparing them with some user input text, i have to normalize any type of dashes/hyphens to simple hyphen/minus (ascii 45).

The possible dashes we have to convert are:

```
Minus(−) U+2212 &minus; or &#x2212; or &#8722;
Hyphen-minus(-) U+002D &#45;
Hyphen(-) U+2010
Soft Hyphen   U+00AD  &shy;
Non-breaking hyphen  U+2011  &#8209
Figure dash(‒)  U+2012 (8210) &#x2012; or &#8210;
En dash(–) U+2013 (8211) &ndash;, &#x2013; or &#8211;
Em dash(—) U+2014 (8212) &mdash;, &#x2014; or &#8212;
Horizontal bar(―) U+2015 (8213) &#x2015; or &#8213;
```

These all have to be converted to Hyphen-minus(-) using gsub.
I've used **CharDet** gem to detect the character encoding type of the fetched string. It's showing **windows-1252**. I've tried **Iconv** to convert the encoding to ascii. But it's throwing an exception **Iconv::IllegalSequence**.

ruby -v => ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin9.8.0]
rails -v => Rails 2.3.5
mysql encoding => 'latin1'

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Caveat: I know nothing about Ruby, but you have problems that are nothing to do with the programming language that you are using.*

You don't need to convert `Hyphen-minus(-) U+002D &#45;` to `simple hyphen/minus (ascii 45)`; they're the same thing.

You believe that the database encoding is `latin1`. The statement "My data is encoded in ISO-8859-1 aka latin1" is up there with "The check is in the mail" and "Of course I'll still love you in the morning". All it tells you is that it is a single-byte-per-character encoding.

Presuming that "fetched string" means "byte string extracted from the database", `chardet` is very likely quite right in reporting `windows-1252` aka `cp1252` -- however this may be by accident as `chardet` sometimes seems to report that as a default when it has exhausted other possibilities.

(a) These Unicode characters cannot be decoded into `latin1` or `cp1252` or `ascii`:

```
Minus(−) U+2212 &minus; or &#x2212; or &#8722;
Hyphen(-) U+2010
Non-breaking hyphen  U+2011  &#8209
Figure dash(‒)  U+2012 (8210) &#x2012; or &#8210;
Horizontal bar(―) U+2015 (8213) &#x2015; or &#8213;
```

What gives you the impression that they may possibly appear in the input or in the database?

(b) These Unicode characters can be decoded into `cp1252` but not `latin1` or `ascii`:

```
En dash(–) U+2013 (8211) &ndash;, &#x2013; or &#8211;
Em dash(—) U+2014 (8212) &mdash;, &#x2014; or &#8212;
```

These (most likely the EN DASH) are what you really need to convert to an ascii hyphen/dash. What was in the string that `chardet` reported as `windows-1252`?

(c) This can be decoded into `cp1252` and `latin1` but not `ascii`:

```
Soft Hyphen   U+00AD  &shy;
```

If a string contains non-ASCII characters, any attempt (using `iconv` or any other method) to convert it to `ascii` will fail, unless you use some kind of "ignore" or "replace with `?`" option. Why are you trying to do that?